# Which package we need to install to remove -lgcc_s error?

Tags: linux

I am getting this error when i compile my test file in linux centOS7.

```
/usr/bin/ld : cannot find -lgcc_s

collect2: error: ld return 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

It means, it's not finding an existing library `gcc_s`.

One reason for this, this is because although `libgcc` is present, it may not be not in the paths known to `ldconfig`.

**try this by doing**

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libgcc
```

if the output show that the is link to `libgcc` corresponds to paths that you have listed above?

A workaround for you may be to add the link to the relevant library to your compile command,  [for example](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1750758), it will do the job.

```
g++ yourprogram.cpp -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/
```

Comment: `sudo` is not needed for `ldconfig -p`